# How to setText in SecondActivity onItemClick

Tags: java, android, listview

I need to setText in SecondActivity, when item is clicked, but text must be different according to item. I've got an error when item is clicked and it doesn't work. Can you tell me how to setText from First Activity to Second?

First Activity:

```
final String[] setP = { "P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9" };

final ListAdapter theAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, setP);
final ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.theListView2);
theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);

theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String itemPicked = "Selected: " + String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, itemPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("newsId", "1");
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);


        String chosen = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));

        if (chosen == "P1") { // doesn't work
            SecondActivity.displayR.setText("EXAMPLE FOR P1");
        } else if (chosen.equals("P2")) { // doesn't work
            SecondActivity.displayR.setText("EXAMPLE FOR P2");
        }
    }
});
```

and SecondActivity:

```
public static TextView displayR;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

    displayR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textR);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put your choosen item's name in to Intent and get it's name in second activity from Intent like this:

first activity

```
theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String itemPicked = "Selected: " + String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, itemPicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("newsId", "1");


        String chosen = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));

        if (chosen == "P1") { // doesn't work
            intent.putExtra("name", "p1");
        } else if (chosen.equals("P2")) { // doesn't work
            intent.putExtra("name", "p2");
        }

        MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

second activity

```
public static TextView displayR;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);

    displayR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textR);
    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    displayR.setText(name);
}
```

Comment: Activity opens without error, but there's no TextView